# PHP - How to display current user details with id?

Tags: php, mysql, session, display

I want to display a user's info on an account details page **(account.php)**. I've already made the page unavailable for users who are not logged in. So, now my problem is I don't know how to connect to my database and fetch the data and only display their account info on the page. Each of my user has an id. The info for each user I want to display is the **username, gender, and email**. My database name is "appDevDB" and the table is "users", with the above entities. How do I do this?

Comment: After login store the id in session $_SESSION['id']=$current_user_id; and on account page fetch the account info using $_SESSION['id'] like select * from users where id=$_SESSION['id']

Comment: @JYoThI comment is the answer. I mean you could go another step further and save commonly used user fields into the session on authentication as well for faster reference to the auth user details on other page. eg if you are displaying the name of the logged in user on every page it would be better to save name in the session so you dont need to go to the database for it everytime

Comment: if user modified any details after login like he update his name ram into ram s . means it would not reflect in session @JasonJoslin storing all the fields in session is  not good approach . i think so .

Comment: @JYoThI yeah good point. I guess to rectify that just make sure you update the session on any update/editing actions. I was just thinking for performance using session as a small cache store would be faster. however for this project the difference would be so small, its no issue going to the DB for every call. I have voted your answer

Comment: yeah thanks @JasonJoslin

Answer (score 2):

Follow my steps :

1) Put `session_start();` on very top on each page wherever going to use session variable.

2) After login store the currently logged user id in session `$_SESSION['id']=$current_user_id;`

3) An account page fetch the account info using `$_SESSION['id']` like

```
select * from users where id=$_SESSION['id']
```

Comment: Hi, when i try to store session in $_SESSION['id']=$current_user_id; i get this error: Undefined variable: current_user_id

Comment: $current_user_id;  replaced with your logged in user id .

Comment: all my users have different id numbers though, how do i store the current user's info? like the user who is currently logged in?

Comment: while checking login authentication. if user is valid .fetch him id from database and store in session .